# Cannot get to execute my java method from JS

Tags: codenameone

I perused the other threads on that topic but still I cannot get my code to work hence seeking help.

Here is the code:

```
    BrowserComponent bc = new BrowserComponent();
    bc.setDebugMode(true);
    bc.setPage("<html><body></body></html>", null);
    JavascriptContext context = new JavascriptContext(bc);
    bc.addWebEventListener("onLoad", e -> {
        {
            JSObject syso = (JSObject) context.get("{}");
            syso.set("print", new JSFunction() {
                @Override
                public void apply(JSObject self, Object[] args) {
                    System.out.println(StringUtils.injectArgs("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {9}", args));
                }
            });
            context.set("window.syso", syso);
        }

        {
            JSObject syso = (JSObject) context.get("syso");
            syso.call("print", "I", "am", "in", "syso");
        }
    });
```

And here is the error:

```
    Error trying to execute js if (typeof(ca_weblite_codename1_js_JavascriptContext_LOOKUP_TABLE1) == 'undefined'){ca_weblite_codename1_js_JavascriptContext_LOOKUP_TABLE1=[]};(ca_weblite_codename1_js_JavascriptContext_RETURN_VAR_call_3=(ca_weblite_codename1_js_JavascriptContext_LOOKUP_TABLE1[0]).call(ca_weblite_codename1_js_JavascriptContext_LOOKUP_TABLE1[1], 'print', 'I', 'am', 'in', 'syso'))
[EDT] 0:0:0,2 - Codename One revisions: 0576ed169fa3bf9f9fe32b3ad516f3aeee60a66c

[EDT] 0:0:0,3 - Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException - Failed to execute javascript ca_weblite_codename1_js_JavascriptContext_RETURN_VAR_call_3=(ca_weblite_codename1_js_JavascriptContext_LOOKUP_TABLE1[0]).call(ca_weblite_codename1_js_JavascriptContext_LOOKUP_TABLE1[1], 'print', 'I', 'am', 'in', 'syso').  The error was netscape.javascript.JSException: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '(ca_weblite_codename1_js_JavascriptContext_LOOKUP_TABLE1[0]).call(ca_weblite_codename1_js_JavascriptContext_LOOKUP_TABLE1[1], 'print', 'I', 'am', 'in', 'syso')')
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute javascript ca_weblite_codename1_js_JavascriptContext_RETURN_VAR_call_3=(ca_weblite_codename1_js_JavascriptContext_LOOKUP_TABLE1[0]).call(ca_weblite_codename1_js_JavascriptContext_LOOKUP_TABLE1[1], 'print', 'I', 'am', 'in', 'syso').  The error was netscape.javascript.JSException: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '(ca_weblite_codename1_js_JavascriptContext_LOOKUP_TABLE1[0]).call(ca_weblite_codename1_js_JavascriptContext_LOOKUP_TABLE1[1], 'print', 'I', 'am', 'in', 'syso')')
    at com.codename1.javascript.JavascriptContext.call(JavascriptContext.java:975)
    at com.codename1.javascript.JavascriptContext.call(JavascriptContext.java:862)
    at com.codename1.javascript.JavascriptContext.call(JavascriptContext.java:807)
    at com.codename1.javascript.JSObject.call(JSObject.java:960)
    at net.etceterum.app.javascript.JSEngine.lambda$0(JSEngine.java:105)

         //JSEngine.java:105 = syso.call("print", "I", "am", "in", "syso");

at net.etceterum.app.javascript.JSEngine$$Lambda$9/30625616.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(EventDispatcher.java:459)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.access$100(EventDispatcher.java:45)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher$CallbackClass.run(EventDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1114)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1058)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:946)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Steve might be more qualified to answer that but it looks to me like `syso` might be undefined at this stage

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to call "syso" as a function, with parameters "print", "I", "am", "in", "syso".   In JS, what you've done is

`window.syso('print','I','am','in','syso');`

Change

```
syso.call("print", "I", "am", "in", "syso");
```

to

```
syso.call("print", new Object[]{"I", "am", "in", "syso"});
```

And it will work.

Comment: Hello Steve, thanks for your help.  That runs smoothly now.  It's that smooth that I dont see anything happening actually.  One, I don't see anything in the output where as syso is supposed to system.out the args and two, my debugger does not stop on the System.out.println line when it executes.  I'm really wondering...

Comment: Raaaahhh... Sorry.  I had scrambled my code.  It works as you said.  Thanks a lot.